# C++: Trying to declare and define templated class within templated class. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, templates

```
#ifndef SIMPLE_BST_HPP
#define SIMPLE_BST_HPP

#include <vector>

template <class T>
class SimpleBST {

public:

    SimpleBST(std::vector<T>);


    template <class T>
    class BSTNode
    {


    };

};


#endif
```

However, I get this error when compiling:

```
In file included from SimpleBST.cpp:1:0:
SimpleBST.hpp:14:12: error: declaration of ‘class T’
  template <class T>
            ^
SimpleBST.hpp:6:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’
 template <class T>
           ^
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
SimpleBST.hpp:14:12: error: declaration of ‘class T’
  template <class T>
            ^
SimpleBST.hpp:6:11: error:  shadows template parm ‘class T’
 template <class T>
           ^
```

Does anyone know why I am unable to define the BSTNode? I will eventually make the node private, but at this point, I am just trying to declare a class within the SimpleBST that can be used as the basic node to store the elements of my binary search tree.

Thanks!

Comment: You're using T twice, use a different identifier.

Comment: Usually it does not make much sense to make the node a template at all. Your tree is a tree of `T`s, so your node will only store `T`s.

Comment: What people are trying to say is: you don't need to make your node class a template, drop the second `template <class T>`.

Comment: @T.C. more accurately, the Node allready has a template specifier, as `SimpleBST<T>::Node`.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Hmm. I see what you guys are saying. I will play with this a little bit, and respond again here. IdeaHat, so what you are saying is that my node class already knows of the existence of some type T, and that I am free to use T within the node class?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the classes you are creating, it does not make sense that you are using a class template for the nested class.

You don't want `SimpleBST<double>` to contain `BSTNode<int>`.

Make `BSTNode` a simple nested type under `SimpleBST<T>`.

```
template <class T>
class SimpleBST {

public:

    SimpleBST(std::vector<T>);

    class BSTNode
    {
    };

};
```

Comment: Ah, yes, this compiles now. I will play with this and try to understand why this is the case. Thanks!